# How to round number to the closest 50 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need help with the following.

I would like to round calculated numbers this way:

Example: 132 goes to 150, 122 goes to 100

- 0-24,99 goes to 0
- 25-74,99 goes to 50
- 75-124,99 goes to 100
- and so on..

I need to do this in JS because user will insert some values, then the number will be calculated and this number needs to bi *rounded*.

Comment: This is custom round, you need to use if..else or switch case and decide what should be the rounded number for given range.

Comment: `function roundToNearest(nearest, number) { return  Math.round(number/nearest) * nearest; }` should do the trick.

Comment: use Math.ceil(value / 100) * 100... it will give answer

Comment: @geminiousgoel so how will that give you 50?

Comment: @epascarello its just an idea to work..if you want round-off of 50 then multiply and divide by 50, similarly for the case of 10. Even Math.ceil can be used twice for more accurate results. Example first use for value 10 and then for 5. Also, if you want to round-off to lower value , you had option to use Math.floor.

Answer (score 26):

Try this .`Math.round(num / 50)*50`

```js
function roundnum(num){
return Math.round(num / 50)*50;
}
console.log(roundnum(22))
console.log(roundnum(74))
console.log(roundnum(89))
console.log(roundnum(162))
console.log(roundnum(190))
console.log(roundnum(224))
console.log(roundnum(225))
```

Comment: `Number.prototype.nearest = function(n) { return Math.round(this / n) * n}`
`const num = 534; console.log(num.nearest(50)) // 550`

Answer (score 10):

From what I've understood from your number ranges you are trying to round to intervals of 50.

To do this all that is needed is to divide your number by 50, round that and then times it by 50 again, like so

```
Math.round(num / 50) * 50
```

This function can be adapted to round to pretty much any number you would want just by changing the numbers used to times and divide.

Comment: I thought that too, but after reading it a few more times it dawned on me he wants the closest 50-number.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Thanks, I've edited my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```js
function closest50(number) {
  return Math.round(number / 50) * 50
}

console.log(closest50(0));
console.log(closest50(24));
console.log(closest50(24.99));
console.log(closest50(63));
console.log(closest50(132));
```

This divides the number by 50, rounds it down and than multiplies by 50 again.